# Trying to find a way to "shrink" a very large number

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, largenumber

I'm trying to find a way to get a million digit+ number into a readable format 
(example a*b^c+d) 
Is their an easy/fast way to do this in python? Or is there some other language I should be using?

This is what I'm trying now and its very slow

```
            n = 2**1234567890
            base = 32582657

            base2 = 1
            nb= 0

            while base2 < n :
                    base2 = base * base2
                    nb = nb + 1
            base2 = base2 / base
            nb = nb - 1
            j = n - base2

            if n == (base**nb) + j :
                    print('They match')
```

Thank you

Comment: How about Scientific Notation?

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: I need exact number so scientific notation won't work. And yes it is a math question, but I need programming to solve it.

Comment: How do you propose to transform a million digit number into a less-than-a-million digits without losing information?  Surely that is, in general, impossible.  Are you dealing with a particular number that has some property allowing you to accomplish what you want?

Comment: Any number can be compressed in this way, I'm just looking to speed up my process.  For instance 9699690 = 90*325^2+193440

Comment: I don't understand in what sense that constitutes "compression."  You started with 7 digits (9699690) and represented the same number with 12 digits and 3 operators (90*325^2+193440).  If you're trying to get a readable format, how is that progress?  Why didn't you choose 90*326^2+134850 instead?  What's the algorithm that you're trying to speed up?

Comment: In the edited version of the question you seem to be finding the largest nb such that `base**nb <= n`.  Why can't you use `nb=int(log(n)/log(base))` and get rid of the while loop?

Comment: You're asking for an algorithm that needs to essentially factorize rather large numbers. The largest known prime is only 17 million digits long and that took a LONG time using hundreds of thousands of CPUs doing trillions of calculations a second. It took 3.6 days just to *verify* the number once they already knew the factors! Don't be surprised if your Python program goes a bit slow :) http://www.mersenne.org/primes/?press=M57885161

Comment: How will the million-digit number be created/acquired?

Answer (score 0):

You could compress the digits in this form:

```
number = 3245552

if len(str(number)) > 6:
    zeroes = len(str(number)) - 2
    decimal = number / 10.0**zeroes
    print round(decimal, 2), '* 10 ^', zeroes
```

Output: `32.46 * 10 ^ 5`

Comment: I need the math to be reversible.  32.46*10^5 = 3246000

Comment: There isn't really a way to compress such a digit without loosing some data. Well at least not any that I know of. @JohnFitch